# How do sidekiq-unique-jobs algorithms treat dead jobs?

Tags: sidekiq

The sidekiq-unique-jobs gem includes a few different ways of defining when a subsequent job should be enqueued (or suppressed) based on where a previous job is in its lifecycle:

- while_executing
- until_executing
- until_executed
- until_timeout
- until_and_while_executing

These are geared towards preventing more than one identical job from running at the same time, and/or preventing more than one identical job from being in the queue at the same time.

Is there a way to treat dead jobs as executing or waiting to execute?

From what I've seen, if a job goes to the Dead queue, uniqueness doesn't prevent an identical job from immediately being enqueued and going straight to the same place.